# ImproperlyConfigured exception but it works anyway

Tags: python, django, docker, cron

I have following code:

```py
import django

def process():

    django.setup()

    from django.conf import settings
    print(settings.configured())
    print(settings.SECRET_KEY)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process()
```

When I try to run it with all the env variables defined with cron inside docker, I get:

```
cron_1          | Traceback (most recent call last):
cron_1          |   File "process_tasks.py", line 16, in <module>
cron_1          |     process()
cron_1          |   File "process_tasks.py", line 8, in process
cron_1          |     django.setup()
cron_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
cron_1          |     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
cron_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
cron_1          |     self._setup(name)
cron_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
cron_1          |     % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
cron_1          | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
cron_1          | app.settings.dev
cron_1          | True
cron_1          | dev
```

When I run it without cron, I dont get the exception.
But everything seems to work fine, eventhough there is this exception. For the cronjob, I am using:

```
* * * * * root . /root/env.sh; cd /app/; python3 process_tasks.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

In env.sh file, there are just env variables written as `export VAR=VALUE` list.

So my question is, why the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part of the error message is:

```
> You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

You can do this in you

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
```

or you could export it in your `env.sh`

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

Comment: Problem is, its actually defined in the env.sh and if I try to getenv it in the code, I see it, but the exception is thrown anyway. Rest of the code works, it wouldnt if settings were improperly loaded.

Comment: I think you'll have to add more details. You say *rest of code works*, but there is no other code in your question.

Comment: the print statements wouldnt work if settings werent properly loaded, but all other works, like querying models, saving to database etc.